# SqlBulkCopy invalid column length...but it's not

Tags: sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

My `SqlBulkCopy` command is throwing an exception saying

> Received an invalid column length from the bcp client for colid 24.

If I look at the 24th (starting at 0) column as shown in Sql Server Mgmt Studio it's the SpaceID column.  If I do it via the DataTable it's the Title column.  Both are defined in the database as being a `varchar(255)`.  None of my columns for that are too big though.  In the loop where I add the values to the DataTable I checked the length of each and reported on any larger than 254 characters and there are none.

What else could be causing this issue?

Comment: Your column mappings could be messed up.  Configure the mappings explicitly to troubleshoot.  Otherwise post the table DDL and a console app repro.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.columnmappings?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlBulkCopy_ColumnMappings

Comment: Apparently it doesn't like that the SQL table had more columns than the DataTable that was being used for the bulk upload.

Comment: When facing "Received an invalid column length from the bcp client for colid 'n'" error, 'n' could be any number related to the column. The hint I found in your question which resolved my issue was - (starting at 0) column, counting from 0th index in the db table helped to find out the related column & modify its length accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue is Boolean type, Azure read my .dsv file, and understand that "f" or 0 in my columns its for false, so INT, or any string types is not actual for this column. I changed datatype of my sink column as BIT and its worked for me.